# Can "Select on Key Release" be turned off?

Tags: shortcut, select

In *Edit Mode* I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the Toolbar to then press my next hotkey. I have just discovered that if I **hold** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and drag my cursor, upon **release** it will select whatever option my cursor was last on. Is there a way to turn off this "Select on Key Release" feature?

Comment: To be honest, I've never used that key combination because just pressing 'T' will toggle the toolbar on and off and you can click the required option from that.

Comment: I prefer using keybinds when I can, it helps efficiency. You did make me think about why I want to use the "Shift + Space" menu in the first place. I think it's mostly useful for when I forget a keybind. However the shortcut for "Spin" is Shift + Space, then Shift + 0; there doesn't appear to be a default shortcut for it without opening the "Shift + Space" toolbar menu first.

Comment: You could always add Spin to the quick favourites menu and then add a shortcut key to that.